# Select SQL Table Columns with given range

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, range, period

I do have this table in my SQL database

```
Acc ID   Perod1   Perod2   Perod3   Perod4   Perod5
---------------------------------------------------
1-001      30       40       70       80       70
2-002      50       60       80       60       70
3-004      60       70       80       50       40
```

I need to select above "Perod" columns in given range. Like "Perod1 to Perod3" or "Perod2 to Perod5". Need to write a SQL select query which can select columns with given range. Please help me.

I need SQL query like below

```
Select 
    Perod1, Perod2 
from 
    tbl_accPeriod 
where 
    AccID = '1-001'
```

but "Perod" columns I should able to give dynamically. one time it can be "Perod1 to Perod2" and next time it should be "Perod1 to Perod4". I want to do that without add IF condition.

Comment: can you explain your question?

Comment: Do you need all the results in a single column? merged? or column wise?

Comment: Explain more in above aging

Comment: dynamic query support is different for different databases. What RDBMS is yours?

Comment: Do you realize how badly normalized your data is? Every period should be a separate row.

Comment: well database structure is already done by previously . I just want to do a one report only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this,

```
DECLARE @SQLCols AS NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500)
Declare @from int = 1
Declare @to int = 2

Set @SQLCols = 'Perod' + Cast(@from as Varchar(10))

WHILE(@from < @to)

BEGIN

        Set @SQLCols = @SQLCols + ',Perod' + Cast(@from + 1 as Varchar(10))   

        SELECT @from = @from + 1

END

Set @SQLQuery = 'Select ' + @SQLCols + ' from tbl_accPeriod'

execute @SQLQuery
```